# Using an argument as a variable error Python

Tags: python, excel, variables

Trying to use the int variable `"row"` as an argument in the `Excelread` row so I can iterate. I get errors as python is not recognizing as an int input?

```
from automagica import *
Row = 2

current_run = ExcelReadCell(path="C:\\Users\\jmoloney\\Downloads\\Medicaid.xlsx", r=Row, c=1, sheet=None)
Row = Row+1
print(current_run)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ExcelReadCell() got an unexpected keyword argument 'r'
```

Comment: `ExcelReadCell` takes a `cell` argument giving a cell name, like `"A1"`. The one that takes `r` and `c` is `ExcelReadRowCol`.

Comment: The problem is the parameter, not the argument.  It says that `ExcelReadCall` doesn't have a parameter named `r`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the formatting is off, must use

ExcelReadRowCol(path="C:\Users\jmoloney\Downloads\Medicaid.xlsx", r=Row, c=1, sheet=None)

vs ExcelReadCell(xxx